# FFMPEG convert MP4 to other Video Formats without loss of quality

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have an MP4 video file of 720p and I want to convert it to different video formats using FFMPEG, 
I'm using FFMPEG 4.4 under Windows 10.
The list of the targeted formats are listed below : 
.asf, .f4v, .ismv, .m4v, .mpeg, .avi, .flv, .mkv, .mov, .mts, .mxf, .nut, .vob, .wmv 
I tried this command but the output is losing quality and for some formats the conversion process is very slow.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.asf (same for other formats)
```

Answer (score 1):

First try

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy output.xxx
```

This will keep the video & audio streams as is. As long as the output format supports the input codecs, you are good to go. For incompatible containers, you need to reencode and an option argument to set encoding quality depends on which codec. Note FFmpeg may generate output with incompatible codecs, so make sure to try all your outputs and note which one didn't result in working video.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast reply, I'm new on FFMPEG, I don't know what is reencoding, codecs, container, I will search for it, I will try your command.

Comment: Start by learning the difference between formats (mp4, mov, avi, etc.) and streams (which are generally compressed forms of video or audio feeds, and algorithms to compress the original video are called encoders and the one to decompress is called decoders. Since they are often come in pairs, we call them codecs). If you can keep the streams untouched and just copy them in a new container (file) with a different format, then you preserve the original unchanged. That's what `-c copy` option commands to do.